# What is the preferred format for tagging expansions?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I noticed there are currently tags like *catan-cities-and-knights* and *dominion-alchemy*, but also *seafarers-of-catan* and *pegasus*. Should expansion tags be prefixed with the core game name? If so, should it be *catan-cities-and-knights* or *settlers-of-catan-cities-and-knights*? The latter seems rather lengthy, but when would it be ok to abbreviate? Would *catan-seafarers-of-catan* be redundant?

Comment: Just noticed that the expansion is not called Seafarers of Catan (which is what I've always called it for some reason). It's Catan Seafarers.

Comment: Over on SmarterGamer we would have done settlers-of-catan, seafarers-expansion. Not sure I think that's best, just how we did it there.

Answer (score 7):

I think we should have a single tag for the game and a tag for the expansion. Just like dealing with languages and versions on SO.

So you should have setlers-of-catan (or short catan) and seafarers, cities-and-nights, possibly even: expansion-seafarers and seafarers-cities-and-nights.

Comment: That works fine until two games end up having expansions with identical names.  If that happens, you've suddenly linked two games that have nothing to do with each other with a common tag.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, an expansion could have the same name as a completely different game.  For example, Dominion's expansions would have tags of intrigue, seaside, alchemy, and prosperity... of those, I could see all but seaside as conflicting with games of the same name.

Answer (score 7):

I think the question should be tagged with the common name of the expansion (like `dominion-alchemy` or `seafarers-of-catan`) and tagged with the name of the parent game (like `dominion` or `settlers-of-catan`).

We shouldn't go out of the way to format the expansion's tag to include the parent game's name if that's not how people refer to it.  If the game is called "Seafarers of Catan" I don't see a need to jam "Settlers of Catan" into the Seafarers tag.

Comment: The problem with going with the manufacturer's official name for stuff is that it's sometimes rather lengthy. For example, the tag using the official full name of the BSG Pegasus expansion would be: battlestar-galactica-the-board-game-pegasus-expansion. Obviously that's a bit excessive.

Comment: Yeah, okay, that's not quite what I meant.  I'll try to rephrase.  My intent was more that if they call it "Seafarers of Catan" we shouldn't go crazy trying to shoehorn "Settlers of Catan" in there too.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's more benefit than detriment to lean toward having the base game and expansion be in the same tag. Powerlord has pointed out that having multiple different games refer to the same tag unnecessarily links two different games. If I search for such a tag and find 1200 questions under it, I get no visibility into just how many questions pertain to it, whereas if we have one tag per game and one tag per game+expansion, it's immediately clear. The only downside I see is a long tag such as "arkham-horror-curse-of-the-dark-pharaoh" which is long but easily forgivable in exchange for the clarity, in my opinion.  The only issue is the tag size limit prevents this (and I don't know how easy it is to appeal to have it lengthened).

Answer (score -2):

Three tags: [game], [expansion] name and the tag "expansion".

Comment: I think `expansion` adds nothing here, personally.  We should be wary of too many tags.